# How to control automatic memoisation in Haskell (GHC)?

Tags: performance, haskell, monads, ghc, memoization

Here's a small program that prints the first 40 fibonacci numbers ***thrice*** -

```
module Main where

fib :: Int -> Int
fib 1 = 1
fib 2 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)

main :: IO ()
main = run >> run >> run
  where
    run = mapM_ (print . fib) [1..40]
```

If I compile it with `ghc Main.hs`, then the computational part of "run" is saved by GHC, so that executing `run` three times takes roughly the same time as running it once. This was quite a surprise! I was under the impression that monadic effects are not automatically memoised like this.

Also, if I compile it with `ghc -O2 Main.hs` then the memoisation is lost. (Atleast on my machine with ghc 7.10.3)

How can I predict when something is going to be memoised? Is there some documented rule of thumb somewhere? How does this play with `unsafePerformIO` and the like?

Comment: FWIW: `run` is evaluated just once even with `-O2` here on my machine (so I don't observe your "caching is lost" behavior).

Comment: @DanielWagner Interesting! What GHC version are you on? I'm on GHC 7.10.3.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Yup!

Comment: @AnupamJain 7.10.2 -- I'm surprised this behavior has changed across point releases!

Comment: @DanielWagner: Can confirm, GHC 7.10.3 on Windows using stack. `-O2` provides a better `fib`, but all three `run` calculated it anew. `ddump-simpl` reveals that `--O0` floats `run :: IO ()` outwards, whereas `-O2` inlines it into `mainK :: Int# -> State# ... -> (State#, () #)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here `run` is a constant expression. So, like any other constant expression, it only gets evaluated once. Oh, the I/O actions it encodes get *executed* three times, but the expression (or rather, its subexpressions) evaluate only once.

My guess (and it's only a guess) is that not naming it would probably cause it to be re-evaluated each time. As in

```
main = do
  mapM_ (print . fib) [1..40]
  mapM_ (print . fib) [1..40]
  mapM_ (print . fib) [1..40]
```

would *probably* evaluate it multiple times. But I'm not 100% certain.

Now, if `run` was a *function*:

```
main = run 40 >> run 40 >> run 40
  where
    run n = mapM_ (print . fibs) [1..n]
```

then it would *probably* evaluate multiple times. I think GHC would avoid keeping the result of an arbitrary function call like that.

Comment: "Oh, the I/O actions it encodes get executed three times, but the expression (or rather, its subexpressions) evaluate only once." I'm not sure I understand that. How does the expression get evaluated beyond the first `bind`? It looks like some ghc magic which optimises the case when the result of the IO part is not being used.

Comment: Suppose I write `foo = print (2 + 2)`. Now `print` is an ordinary function; it's result just happens to be a data structure that encodes an I/O operation. If you execute that operation 3 times, the sub-expression `2 + 2` is only evaluated once, even though the `print` I/O action executes 3 times...